# Why can't create new folder/file eventhough it's still have free memory

Tags: linux

I want to create new file/folder in folder Data, but although it's still have memory free (free 9G/total 26G) can't do it. Folder Data was mounted from /dev/mmcblk1p3.

```
root@imx6qsabresd:/Data/logCom# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root              3212144    645868   2383392  21% /
devtmpfs                346484         4    346480   0% /dev
tmpfs                   510836         0    510836   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   510836      8564    502272   2% /run
tmpfs                   510836         0    510836   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                   510836     40948    469888   8% /tmp
tmpfs                   510836    118452    392384  23% /opt/JCM
tmpfs                   510836        72    510764   0% /var/volatile
/dev/mmcblk1p1         1103740    102384   1001356   9% /Download
/dev/mmcblk1p3        24735004  14204956   9250512  61% /Data
root@imx6qsabresd:/Data/logCom# mkdir abc
mkdir: can't create directory 'abc': No space left on device
root@imx6qsabresd:/Data/logCom#
```

Hope everybody help please !!!

Comment: Please show the output of `df -i`.

Comment: ``root@imx6qsabresd:/opt/JCM/bin/apl# df -i
df: invalid option -- 'i'
BusyBox v1.24.1 (2017-12-12 20:50:25 JST) multi-call binary.

Usage: df [-PkmhT] [FILESYSTEM]...``

Comment: ``df -i `` can't do it. This cmd isn't supported in my machine (imx6)

Comment: I think you have to change some configs for busybox to enable df -i as this answer suggests https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399119/275172

Comment: What Gerald is probably suggesting, is that your disk may be out of inodes (file "IDs"). This can't be fixed (easily). But running out of inodes is quite unusual, so you probably have a lot of files (and I mean A LOT A LOT) somewhere on your disk, so you should investigate where these are coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments suggest, it is likely that you ran out of [inodes](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode).

A busybox'able way to check inodes is (at least on x86) should be:

```
stat -f -c "%d free of %c total" .
```

Where

- `-f` gives filesystem info instead of directory
- `-c "%d"` gives free inodes on filesystem
- `-c "%c"` gives total inodes on filesystem
- `.` is the current path, so the filesystem you are currently on. You can also point to the fs directly by using `/dev/mmcblk1p3` instead.

This happens if you have a massive (or as Malik states "A LOT A LOT" ^^) amount of small files. I ran into this issue while logging API requests to files, where I had 97% free space on device, but 0 free inodes. ‍♂️

Comment: Thank you for your suggest. I implement that cmd, ``0 free of 1581056``, really free inodes = 0. I understanded !!!